# How to use columns via a subreport

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder3.0

I am having some trouble with a report. I am trying to create an A5 booklet, with one page per Subject for all Subjects a Student is taught. What I have currently is:

1) A Main report that's formatted as a single A4 sheet, with the Front and back pages of the booklet. This is all static and works fine. At the end of the report it calls number #2 below, which is a SubReport

2) A Subreport that's formatted as an A4 sheet but with two columns, so it basically returns two A5 sheets in portrait on an A4 sheet in landscape. This report has a List which generates an A5 sheet per Subject. Ran on its own, this works exactly as I expect

My problem is that when I run the main report (which includes #2 as a **subreport**), the subeport breaks down - what it returns is simply a single A5 page on the A4 sheet, instead of doing what it should be doing and returning two A5 pages side by side on the A5 sheet.

I am kind of at a loss with this - any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

The problem is that subreports inherit the Column settings from their main report, and there's no way to avoid that. The way around it is to recraft the Main Report as an A4 sheet with two A5 columns and simply position the pages appropriately to form the booklet